# Why cant I get libevdev-dev package on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: apt, package-management, cmake

I'm new to Linux and I'm having a hard time with a package. I've been trying to run the ''cmake .'' and I can't because I don't have the libevdev package.

```
~/joycond$ cmake .
-- Checking for module 'libevdev'

--   No package 'libevdev' found
CMake Error at /snap/cmake/876/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:556 (message):
  A required package was not found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /snap/cmake/876/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:778 (_pkg_check_modules_internal)
  CMakeLists.txt:10 (pkg_check_modules)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/louis/joycond/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

When I try to run `sudo apt install libevdev`, it is unable to find it.

```
~$ sudo apt install libevdev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libevdev
```

I saw online that what I needed was libevdev-dev, but...

```
~$ sudo apt install libevdev-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libevdev-dev
```

If anyone could help it would be greatly appreciated since I am now completely lost.

Comment: Did you first run `sudo apt update` followed by `sudo apt install libevdev-dev` ? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: I did run it beforehand and it doesn't work. Thanks, it's good to have a place to ask those questions.

Comment: @1rstLegend did the update *succeed*? in particular was it able to connect to and download from a focal/main respository?

Comment: @N0rbert Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

For any newcomers with the same question, make sure you didn't accidentally uncheck ''Download from internet'' in ''Software and Updates''... I am ashamed.